# Make cmd / powershell / windows use a separate tesseract installation instead of the one from chocolatey

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, tesseract, chocolatey

Some years ago I installed tesseract with chocolatey and forgot about it.

Now I have the problem that when I type a tesseract command in cmd it uses this tesseract instead of an new one I install separateley.

The problem with the one that was installed with chocolatey is that it's outdated and I cant update or uninstall it.

```
choco uninstall tesseract
```

leads to:

`Chocolatey detected you are not running from an elevated command shell`

and then it asks if I want to continue and when I proceed then:

```
tesseract is not installed. Cannot uninstall a non-existent package.
```

but I know that it's at least linked somehow with the tesseract cmd commands even if it's not installed.

How can I make windows / cmd / powershell use the separate tesseract installation instead of the one of chocolatey?

This is what I want to know anyway and I would also like to know how to uninstall tesseract from chocolatey but this isn't necessary to get an answer accepted

Comment: But how can I uninstall tesseract from chocolatey? Yeah I already consideret to uninstall this crap called chocolatey but there is a warning that it can cause all kind of problems when I do that, you think I could just uninstall chocolatey before getting rid of it's tesseract first? @KJ

Comment: Ok I will try, thanks!

Comment: Did you try running powershell or cmd as administrator and then running `choco uninstall tesseract`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I know what the problem was.

I listed all the packages that were installed with chocolatey.

tesseract was not listed, but image2text (or something like that, I don't remember what exactly) and then I remembered that this was what I was using for ocr. I uninstalled it and tesseract also disappeared from cmd. So it looks like image2text also installed tesseract and infested all tesseract commands